# How to remove top left gap from Bootstrap navigation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation menu created using Bootstrap 3. [Here is a demonstration link](http://tinyurl.com/okh3jsr) and I would like to remove the top and left/right margins from the navigation.

[image]

How can I update my code [css/html] to get my desired output?

Comment: Please revise your code sample so everything can fit inside of a jsFiddle or other portable example.  That being said, `.navbar-nav > li > a { border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5; }` is certainly playing a role in the white space.

Answer (score 1):

I think it your nav :

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
```

It's styled with :

```
background-color: #f8f8f8;
border-color: #e7e7e7;
border-radius: 0px !important;
border-top-left-radius: 4px !important;
border-top-right-radius: 4px !important;
```

So you have to add css `"border: none;"`

The bad thing is that you loose the `border radius`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code do the following **corrections**

**First** Remove this HTML

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
           <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  &nbsp;</div>
              </div>
         </div>
```

**Second** Use this CSS

```
body {
        padding-top: 0px !important;
    }
```

Now your top spaces will gone!
Next

**Third** In your first `div` tag remove `container` class and add `row` class like this

```
<div class="row">
```

Now your left and right spaces will gone!

You will get the required result!!